# Count html form inputs with name prefix from asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I've been searching for a while for something similar with no luck. This is what I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="category_1" name="category_1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="category_2" name="category_2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="category_3" name="category_3" />
and so on...
```

**Question**

How can I get number of checkboxes with prefix `category_` in asp.net code behind?

**Edit** Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_CHECKBOXES; i++){}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `length` here?

Comment: @AbZy I mean how many checkboxes there are with prefix `category_`

Comment: You mean you want to add dynamically attributs right?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var categoryInputKeys = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(x=> x.StartsWith("category_")).ToList();
```

after fetching keys you can use them with like that

```
Request.Form[categoryInputKeys[0]]
```

Edit: 
For just counting them that will be enough;

```
var categoryInputCount = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(x=>x.StartsWith("category_")).ToList().Count;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much! +1

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `runat="server"` then you can get access controls in code behind

Comment: That will not help as checkboxes are created "on the fly" using jQuery. I've already tried that. Thank you for suggestion! P.S. If I use your method and create each checkbox using asp's Checkbox control would you provide an easy way for counting them?

Comment: count on client side and call web method from client side and update static property. one more question with help of jquery add attribute (runat = "server")also