# Add item to multiple drop down list based on ID prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and C#. I tried to add some item to my drop down list.
This is my code:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="WH1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="WH2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="WH3" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="WH4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="WH5" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="WH6" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="WH7" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="WH8" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Every drop down list will have the same list. I tried this post
[Count html form inputs with name prefix from asp.net code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295466/count-html-form-inputs-with-name-prefix-from-asp-net-code-behind)
So I can count it and then do some looping and inside that looping I can add some item. But the result of that count is always 0.

```
var categoryInputCount = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(x=>x.StartsWith("WH")).ToList().Count;
```

Am I doing it wrong? even if I can count it, How can I add Item to every drop down list. As far As I know, to add item to drop down list I have to call the ID like this:

```
WH1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem('value 1','value 1'));
```

Comment: is your content in a normal page or is it with a master page

Comment: it is with a master page

Comment: request.form only works with html form fields that have a name attribute.

Comment: @Gauravsa any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Because you want every dropdown list to be the same and you want to be able to do custom sorting, I'll do this all code behind.  Create a Dropdown List holder on your asp page, and populate it by creating a Dictionary/List with the appropriate data. A Dictionary will always be sorted in the ABC way.  A list, you can sort it however you want by using .OrderBy().

You can easily put the list into any asp object on other pages too.

Comment: How could I put the list in to the drop down without repeating all the code? I have eight drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Method can be called with passing as Page, and a list.

Simply call the method:

```
List<DropDownList> list = new List<DropDownList>();

GetListControl(Page, ref list);

private void GetListControl(Control controlCollection, ref List<DropDownList> dropDownCollection)
{
    foreach (Control c in controlCollection.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control childc in c.Controls)
        {
            if (childc != null)
            {
                if (childc is DropDownList)
                {
                    if (childc.ID.StartsWith("WH"))
                    dropDownCollection.Add((DropDownList)childc);
                }

                if (childc.HasControls())
                    GetListControl(childc, ref dropDownCollection);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to googling but I can't find out how to create the 'ControlCollection' and 'dropDownCollection'

Comment: Edited the answer. See how to call the method